# Google Script, just won't copy across item, am lost as to where to insert item

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a script that automatically moves across items if older than 30 days and then delete that item from the original Google Sheet. It deleted items just dandy but can't seem to work out then where to include the last bit. Where it is currently sitting it never writes it to the "Archive" sheet, if I put it infront of the delete row it writes multiple copies.

```
function moveAfterThirty() {
  const sheet_id="179p1U42FXhvhkOoy-uMZ0JSgNCZs7FMkNTj95c2k6_8";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_id);
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
  const dtv = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate() -     30).valueOf();
  let vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var a = [];
  var d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let dv = new Date(r[0]).valueOf();
    if (dv < dtv) {
      a.push(r);
      sh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++)
    }
  });
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, a.length, a[0].length).setValues(a);
}
```

Comment: Your code works just fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You can add the if else at the end to detect and inform you of no data:

```
function moveAfterThirty() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const dtv = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()).valueOf();
  let vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var a = [];
  var d = 0;
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let dv = new Date(r[0]).valueOf();
    if (dv < dtv) {
      a.push(r);
      sh.deleteRow(i + 2 - d++)
    }
  });
  if (a.length > 0) {
    dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, a.length, a[0].length).setValues(a);
  } else (
    console.log("no data")
  )
}
```